# How to plot graphics on diff pictures matlab

Tags: matlab, visualization

I have a matlab program and I need display 2 different pictures in 2 separate figures.

My current attempt at this:

```
fig = figure;
for i = 1:n
   ...// calc matrix A
   ...// calc matrix B
   imagesc(A);
   imagesc(B);
end
```

This code shows both images on the same figure, but i need to show `imagesc(A)` on the figure1(and change it on every iteration), and show `imagesc(B)` on the figure2(and change it on every iteration too).

Is this possible? If so how can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

In Matlab a `figure` corresponds to a individual window. So having two figures will create two windows. Is this what you want or do you want two plots in the same window?

If you want two seperate `figure` windows then try something like:

```
% create the 1st figure
fig1 = figure; 
% create an axes in Figure1
ax1 = axes('Parent', fig1);

% create the 2nd figure
fig2 = figure; 
 % create an axes in Figure2
ax2 = axes('Parent', fig2);

for i = 1:n
   ...// calc matrix A
   ...// calc matrix B
   % draw A in ax1 
   imagesc(A, 'Parent', ax1); 
   % draw B in ax2
   imagesc(B, 'Parent', ax2); 

   % pause the loop so the images can be inspected
   pause;
end
```

If you want a single window but with two charts you can replace the code before the loop with:

```
%create the figure window
fig = Figure;

% create 2 side by side plots in the same window
ax(1) = subplot(211);
ax(2) = subplot(212);

% Insert loop code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the figure() function to switch between what figure window matlab will draw the graph / image to:

```
   for i = 1:n
       ...// calc matrix A
       ...// calc matrix B

       figure(1);
       imagesc(A);

       figure(2);
       imagesc(B);

    end
```

Comment: Could you should add some explanation to your answer, in order to make it more helpful?

Comment: This will be a slow way to implement things.  You are better off using the first approach, manually keeping track of the figure handles.